# What graphics drivers can I install on VirtualBox for games?

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, drivers, graphics-card, gaming

I am trying to play Minecraft on VirtualBox, (I know it's a terrible idea, and I'm not looking for performance or anything) (Win10, but I had the same problem on Ubuntu guest).

The problem I'm encountering is that the driver **"does not support OpenGL"**. I tried installing graphics drivers, but I can't work out what or from where I can install, if there is even something that I can do.

I found something about **insert guest additions CD image**, but I have no idea what to do with that.

So, is there any solution to this? Again, I just want the game to run, I'm not interested in performance or anything.

Comment: I do not believe you can have your own driver with Virtual Box. You cannot with VMware Workstation. Virtualizing Apps get video from the host system.

Comment: See https://superuser.com/questions/1522545/run-application-requiring-opengl-3-3-inside-virtualbox-virtual-machine-windows